# Re validating JTree in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, jtree

I am using Dynamically Generated JTree. and i want to re validate it when a button or label clicked means That root node should be re validate and should not be expand when i click button or label so how to do it?

Comment: You could just replace the `TreeModel`'s root node...

Comment: @MadProgrammer But how to re validate it as usual sorry to as and make u disturb all time bro. :( but can i have example :P

Comment: What do you mean by "revalidate"?  If you want to re-generate the tree, either create a new root node with child nodes and apply it to the `TreeModel` or repalce the `JTree`'s model with a new one...

Comment: you mean you want to make it all collapsed? `tree.collapsePath(root);`

Comment: Well yes right @MadProgrammer i want to re-generate it like if i expand it once and if i click button then it should be back to ideal position. sorry i am very bad at explain. :(

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 sorry but i did not got u. :)

Comment: uhm.. maybe you can have a look at this article..?
http://www.java-tutorial.ch/core-java-tutorial/expande-or-collapse-all-nodes-in-a-jtree

Comment: i do not want to make it collapse @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 i want to like make it in ideal position on click event.

Comment: I am sorry, your explanation is beyond my imagination..

Comment: haha @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 its okey dude just think that i want to reload jtree again and again.:)